# Tensorflow pivoted Cholesky - how to get triangular matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, math

I am very confused about usage of Cholesky decomposition in Tensorflow. There is a pivoted Cholesky in Tensorflow, which I want to use with the solver. `cholesky_solve` in Tensorflow looks liks this:

```
with ops.name_scope(name, 'cholesky_solve', [chol, rhs]):
    y = gen_linalg_ops.matrix_triangular_solve(
        chol, rhs, adjoint=False, lower=True)
    x = gen_linalg_ops.matrix_triangular_solve(
        chol, y, adjoint=True, lower=True)
    return x
```

So, it is assuming that Cholesky decomposition returns triangular matrix, which is used in `matrix_triangular_solve`.

However, there is this note written in the docstring to pivoted Cholesky:

```
Note that, unlike the Cholesky decomposition, `lr` is not triangular even in
  a rectangular-matrix sense. However, under a permutation it could be made
  triangular (it has one more zero in each column as you move to the right).
```

So, the output matrix would not be triangular, so it cannot be used in `cholesky_solve`? And how can it be made triangular under permutation automatically? There is 0 more information about it anywhere in the docs where I have tried to check. I have tried to implement pivoted Cholesky myself for comparison, and indeed it does not provide a triangular matrix output. Is it possible to make the output triangular, or the triangular matrix solver can never be used together with pivoted Cholesky?